# How to set the back ground color to the UIActionSheet in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

I need to change the back ground colour of the action sheet,

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                             delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Create Estimate", @"Record Expense",@"Add Credit",@"Delete Customer", @"Cancel", nil];

    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex=3;

    [actionSheet showInView:appDelegate.window]; // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
    [actionSheet release];
```

please tell how to set the back ground color for action sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the post : [iPhone development: How to create colored or translucent background for UIActionSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181272/iphone-development-how-to-create-colored-or-translucent-background-for-uiactions)

That will be useful for you.

Jim.