# UIActionSheet without background tinting

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, transparent, uiactionsheet

So I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181272/iphone-development-how-to-create-colored-or-translucent-background-for-uiaction)

But it doesn't seem to deal with the issue of making the background NOT tint to a semi-transparent.  I want the content behind the menu with buttons to be clearly visible.  Is this even possible?

This is what I have currently

```
WPSActionSheet *actionSheet = [[WPSActionSheet alloc] initWithCompletion:completion];
  [actionSheet setTitle:@""];
  [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Take Photo"];
  [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Choose from Library"];
  [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Skip This Step"];
  [actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:2];
  [actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
```

which shows this

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you wish to completely eliminate the background around the buttons? Wouldn't they look odd just sort of... hanging there? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Not the background around the buttons, but the tinted background that is over "start by adding a profile image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIActionSheet` will always show the "tinted background". There is no way around this. You can however create your own version of the `UIActionSheet` using a `UIView`.

Comment: Thank you!  It's nice to have a definitive yes or no.  It's been bugging me for days!  How hard is it to implement what you are talking about?  Trying to decide if it's worth the effort.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to create your own. You could always search around google to see if there is an open source class you could use that replicates the `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the alpha and opaque property  of UIActionSheet with delegate method -

```
(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
```

and it will be visible as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make background of UIActionSheet transparent you can subclass it and change layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];


    UIImage* image;
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [[self layer] setContents:(id)image.CGImage];
}
```

To add some custom background just add following code to layoutSubviews:

```
CGRect frame = self.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointZero;

UIImageView* bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
bg.image = [UIImage imageNamed@"YOUR/IMAGE/NAME"];

[self addSubview:bg];
[self sendSubviewToBack:bg];
```

Also you can do all those actions in delegate method

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
```

simply replacing **self** to **actionSheet**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround. The `UIActionSheet`'s superview contains a `UIView` that is used for the tinting. So you can remove the tinting by setting the opacity of this view's layer to 0.

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    NSArray *subviews = actionSheet.superview.subviews;
    UIView *tintView = [subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    [tintView.layer setOpacity:0.0];
}
```

Comment: This is so Risky haha :o - Doesn't work in iOS8 BETA 5

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It worked with iOS 7. In iOS 8 the `UIActionSheet` returns `nil` as its `superview`. Thus my approach is not going to work.