# How to modify the style of the action sheet for MFMailComposeViewController object's cancel button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a MFMailComposeViewController object with a navigation bar in `UIBarStyleBlack` style. When press the Cancel button on the view of MFMailComposeViewController, there will show an action sheet with default style. What I want is to change its style to `UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent`, like:

```
[theActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

But how can I get this action sheet and modify it? Is it possible?

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904540/1260593) may help you

Comment: Thanks @ekims, but the delegate method `willPresentActionSheet:` is even not called. I guess I still need to get this action sheet and set its delegate then.

Comment: did you add the delegate in your class declaration? ie.  **YourViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>**

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple docs:

> The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.

The style of the action sheet is part of the UI and can't be modified. No workaround either, MFMailComposeViewController does not have any public properties/methods that would let you do that.

Comment: Yes, it seems so.. But I can modify its navigation bar's style.. So bad.. Thanks anyway. :)