# Change background color of UIActionSheet iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I tried to change the background color of an `UIActionSheet` like following inside a button click,

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unfollow"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:@"Unfollow"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.parent.view];
    CGSize mySize = actionSheet.bounds.size;
    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, mySize.width, mySize.height);
    UIImageView *redView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
    [redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5]];
    [actionSheet insertSubview:redView atIndex:0];
```

But I failed to change the background color. I got this from stackoverflow. And also I tried to do this with a delegate method,

```
-(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crownImg"];
    theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:32 topCapHeight:32];
    CGSize theSize = actionSheet.frame.size;
    // draw the background image and replace layer content
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);
    [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];
    theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [[actionSheet layer] setContents:(id)theImage.CGImage];
}
```

This also not giving the intended output. Is there a way to change the background color of an `UIActionSheet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, use UIAlertController

try this

```
  #import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
```

add `UIActionSheetDelegate` in your view controller

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> 


yourActionSheet.delegate = self;
yourActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;


- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
[[actionSheet layer] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
}
```

need more ref : [iPhone development: How to create colored or translucent background for UIActionSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181272/iphone-development-how-to-create-colored-or-translucent-background-for-uiaction)

Comment: I did `yourActionSheet.delegate = self;
yourActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;` in button click. Is it ok? But I still have the issue.

Comment: no man where you created the UIActionsheet on that place u need to add the lines , wait

Comment: I'm creating the actionsheet inside the button click method

Comment: Still I have the problem. I'm creating this action sheet inside a table view cell. Is it a problem?

Comment: may be , try in outside and check once it works or not