# Background of a UIActionSheet is not getting set

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I have been following this link to fullfill my task. I want to make my **UIActionSheet** background gray. But nothing happens after following the post!!! I have tried other things too!!
[iPhone development: How to create colored or translucent background for UIActionSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181272/iphone-development-how-to-create-colored-or-translucent-background-for-uiaction)

So far what i have done:

## ON .h file:

Added **UIActionSheetDelegate** and a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActionSheet *popupDelete;
```

## On .m file:

```
self.popupDelete = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Remove",nil];
    self.popupDelete.tag = sender.tag;
    [self.popupDelete showInView:self.view];
```

then added the delegate method as mentioned in the above post:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{

        UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"detail_menu_bg.png"];
        theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:32 topCapHeight:32];
        CGSize theSize = actionSheet.frame.size;
        // draw the background image and replace layer content
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);
        [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];
        theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [[actionSheet layer] setContents:(id)theImage.CGImage];




}
```

And the image detail_menu_bg.png:

[image]

**how to make it work!!!**

Answer (score 0):

1.If you background color rather than showing a background image you can use actionsheetstyle to change the color.

```
actionSheetObj.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque
```

or

```
actionSheetObj.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

2.If you don't want to change the type then u can set the color

- add QuartzCore.framework

Copy this below method in your class

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    [[actionSheet layer] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: did what u suggested!! yet its not working, though willPresentActionsheet method is getting called @Madhu

Comment: have you did this #import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" in our .h file and in viewdidload add this yourActionSheet.delegate = self;
yourActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;@Fay007

Comment: yes you are right uiactionsheet is deprecated from ios8.But this code was working for us.You need to use uialertcontroller instead of actionsheet.